SG Caps on Linux Keyboard Layout
The term sgCaps describes the usage of Caps Lock to totally change the behaviour of certainn keys when Caps Lock is activated (it originates from some swiss german layouts, which allow you to type german umlauts like ä and french or italian accents like é comfortably on one keyboard).
On Windows I used the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator to create my custom keyboard layout, which kind of joins an english, german and french layout.
Just to have an example for the key o
When Caps Lock is not pressed the key behaves like this:
without modifier: o
with SHIFT: O
with ALT GR: ö
with ALT GR + SHIFT: Ö

With activated Caps Lock the key behaves like this:
without modifier: ö
with SHIFT: Ö
with ALT GR: œ
with ALT GR + SHIFT: Œ

So basically in the keyboard layout I define 8 mappings for each key:
Four with caps locks deactivated and four with caps lock activated.
Can I achieve a keyboard layout like this on Linux e.g. with xmodmap and how ?

You should be able to get what you want by copying and modifying existing keyboard layouts to provide each of the layouts you want, and then switching between them as desired. As for using Caps Lock to change layouts, Xfce enables this through the Layout tab of the Keyboard settings dialog, but other Desktop Environments may have different layout changing means.
Custom keyboard layout definitions from the "Ubuntu Community Help Wiki" appears to apply to any X11 setup and may help.
Disclaimer: I've never had the need to try any of this myself, instead using Caps Lock as a Compose key to type the occasional international character.
